# Is there an easy way to shuffle an NSDictionary?

Tags: swift

I am creating a quiz app and I have an NSDictionary with the keys as questions and values as true or false (the answers). I want to randomly select 5 values from this NSDictionary. How can I shuffle the NSDictionary to select values at random?

Here's the NSDictionary

```
let questions: NSDictionary = [
    "A habit is a behavior that has been repeated enough times to become automatic.": true,
    "Spending a conversation talking mostly about yourself is a good way to influence people.": false,
    "In the 7 Habits of Highly Effective People, the Circle of Influence is all of the things inside an individual's control.": true,
    "In The Outliers by Malcolm Gladwell, the author states that the number of hours you practice is more important than your natural talent": true,
    "Think and Grow Rich by Napoleon Hill is based on the idea that anyone can achieve success if they have the right mindset.": true
];
```

Comment: What would "shuffle" even mean for a dictionary? They have no order, so it makes no sense to speak of changing the order. They are already shuffled, in a sense.

Comment: 1. Why do you have a dictionary of questions instead of an array of questions? 2. Why `NSDictionary` instead of a proper Swift dictionary?

Comment: Start over. Make a _struct_ to hold each question. Now make an _array_ of those structs. Now you have something you can shuffle. And never never never use NSDictionary in Swift. Even if what you wanted _was_ a dictionary you wouldn't use it.

Comment: And next time, show some code.

Comment: hi @matt, why should you use NSDictionary in swift?

Comment: Rue, you should **NOT** use an NSDictionary in Swift. You should use the native Dictionary type.

Comment: Apart from the "use native Swift dictionaries instead of NSDictionaries", let me just point out: you probably don't need _any kind_ of dictionary here. When are you looking up these boolean values here by this long question text? I'd guess: probably never. I suspect all you need is a simple `Array<Question>`, where `Question` is just a neat little struct containing a `question: String` and a `correctAnswer: Bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a Swift `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` this code does what you have asked - randomly chooses 5 questions (your example only has 5 questions so they are all chosen):

```
let questions: Dictionary = [
    "A habit is a behavior that has been repeated enough times to become automatic.": true,
    "Spending a conversation talking mostly about yourself is a good way to influence people.": false,
    "In the 7 Habits of Highly Effective People, the Circle of Influence is all of the things inside an individual's control.": true,
    "In The Outliers by Malcolm Gladwell, the author states that the number of hours you practice is more important than your natural talent": true,
    "Think and Grow Rich by Napoleon Hill is based on the idea that anyone can achieve success if they have the right mindset.": true
]

let randomQuestions = questions.keys.shuffled().prefix(5)

for question in randomQuestions {
    // It is safe to force unwrap the answer because we know that `question` exists in the keys
    let answer = questions[question]
    print("Q: \(question), A: \(answer)")
}
```

As other people have commented, a dictionary is possibly not the best data structure to use for this problem. I think a better solution would be to use an array of `Question`s for proper type safety and more readable code:

```
struct Question {
    let title: String
    let answer: Bool
}

let questions = [
    Question(title: "A habit is a behavior that has been repeated enough times to become automatic.", answer: true),
    Question(title: "Spending a conversation talking mostly about yourself is a good way to influence people.", answer: false),
    Question(title: "In the 7 Habits of Highly Effective People, the Circle of Influence is all of the things inside an individual's control.", answer: true),
    Question(title: "In The Outliers by Malcolm Gladwell, the author states that the number of hours you practice is more important than your natural talent", answer: true),
    Question(title: "Think and Grow Rich by Napoleon Hill is based on the idea that anyone can achieve success if they have the right mindset.", answer: true)
]

let randomQuestions = questions.shuffled().prefix(5)

for question in randomQuestions {
    print("Q: \(question.title), A: \(question.answer)")
}
```